# How to use angular material autocomplete in the text input anywhere

Tags: angular

I am try to add angular material autocomplete in Text input.
The idea is when use input like "@" character, the autocomplete dropdown will appear, the user can choose any from the list.

the input can be like 'name=@... and city=@'. before user input @, the dropdown should not show. but once user input @, the autocomplete should show.

```
form class="example-form"><mat-form-field class="example-full-width"><input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" (keydown)="onKeydown($event)" aria-label="Number"   matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"><mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"><mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option></mat-autocomplete></mat-form-field>
```

```
onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const value = input.value;if (value.charAt(value.length - 1) === '@') {
    inputthis.myAutocompleteTrigger.openPanel();
}}
```

The myAutocompleteTrigger.openPanel() seems not working at all. Anyone can help? thanks!

The myAutocompleteTrigger.openPanel() seems not working at all.
I added event.stopPropagation() onKeydown event, but does not help.
Anyone can help? thanks!

Comment: Can you not just use an ngIF on the autoselect? If the first character is "@" then the autoselect is active?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I would like use the select for the part of the input. For example: companyName = @Abc. When the use type @, the dropdown will show, and Abc is one of the option and the user be able to choose it from the list.

Comment: ngIf on the mat-autocomplete? <mat-autocomplete *ngIf="autocompleteEnabled" .../>